# Does Globally convergent homotopy guarantee optimality for non-convex problems?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, non-convex-optimization, global-optimization

I just came across this algorithm in an engineering paper in which I believe the author claims It guarantees global optimality in non-linear systems but never mentioned the convexity of the problem. Is there any algorithm that would find a global optimum in a non-convex problem?

https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/100728

The remark is made in the fourth paragraph of the introduction section:

> Second, the homotopy method is globally convergent, i.e., one may
> choose any initial guesses and the homotopy method is *guaranteed* to
> converge to all solutions with probability one. However, for large-scale load flow problems,
> homotopy method requires exponential increase important
> in the computing capability.

Comment: Could you provide the exact paper or be more specific about the algorithm?

Comment: Here is the reference :

https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/100728

Comment: If you can mention the name of the theorem/remark in the paper which makes this claim, then it would make for a better reference. Nevertheless, thank you for posting your question and the reference, and I hope you get a good answer.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, The remark is made in the fourth paragraph of the introduction section: 

"Second, the homotopy method is globally con- vergent, i.e., one may choose any initial guesses and the
homotopy method is guaranteed to converge to all solutions
Determining steady state solutions of models of large-
with probability one. However, for large-scale load flow
scale interconnected power systems is by far one of the most
problems, the homotopy method requires exponential increase
important problems facing theoretical as well as applied
in the computing capability."